# Google login with Oauth2.0 to many accounts automatically

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I have the next code:

```
public class Controller {
/** Application name. */
private static final String APPLICATION_NAME =
        "Drive API Java Quickstart";

/** Directory to store user credentials for this application. */
private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(
        System.getProperty("user.home"), ".credentials/drive-java-quickstart.json");

/** Global instance of the {@link FileDataStoreFactory}. */
private static FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;

/** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY =
        JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

/** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;

/** Global instance of admin email so we can use it to compare with the email.*/
private static final String ADMIN_EMAIL = "asoriano@as.cloudimpulsion.com";

/** Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
 *
 * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
 * at ~/.credentials/drive-java-quickstart.json
 */
private static final List<String> SCOPES =
        Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE);

static {
    try {
        HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

/**
 * Creates an authorized Credential object.
 * @return an authorized Credential object.
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
    // Load client secrets.
    InputStream in =
            new FileInputStream("secret.json");
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
            GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new              InputStreamReader(in));

    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                    HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                    .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
                    .setAccessType("online")
                    .build();
    Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
            flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
    System.out.println(
            "Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
    return credential;
}

/**
 * Build and return an authorized Drive client service.
 * @return an authorized Drive client service
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static Drive getDriveService() throws IOException {
    Credential credential = authorize();
    return new Drive.Builder(
            HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // Build a new authorized API client service.
    Drive service = getDriveService();
  }
```

Got it following the google Drive quickstart API but I have a problem. This auth code works as: run program -> web browser is oppened -> login with one google account -> give permission (this two last steps have to be done manually).

My intention is to create a program that login an account, do something, login another, do something again, and such a big etc with many other accounts (all accounts from a domain).

The question is: how can I automathize all the auth process so I have to do nothing manually?

I do know all accounts and passwords.

The final objective of this is login all users from a domain and change file owner permission of all the files in some folders to admin.

I have read many doc but haven't found a useful guide or example so I would love an example about how to do it (login automatic, not the final objective).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would like to point out that unless you personally own these X number of accounts you shouldn't have the logins and passwords for them.

The way Oauth2 authentication works is though the web browser credential window.  Once the user grants you access you are given a refresh token and access token that you can use to access the data again.   Technically speaking you could do this once save the refresh token for that account and programmatically go in and access it again.

The second option and probably one that more ideal IMO. Would be for you to create service account credentials.  This will give you a service account email address.   What you will need to do then is grant the service account email address access to the users Google drive account.  A service account is given access the same way a normal user is, by sharing a file or folder on google drive with the service accounts email address.  Then the Service account would have access to do what ever to that file or folder.  So you will have to ask these people to go in and grant you access.  This may or may not be idea depending on how capable the owners of all these accounts are.

Answer:  There is no way to automate the Oauth2 web browser popup window.  That must be done manually at least once.

Comment: But what about that case: -I have a company with many employees. -That employees have editor acces to some shared folders like: "Marketing", "Logistics", etc. -I, as admin, want to have all files in that folders in my name (owner permission) even if they created that documents. Why? -> If someone delete a file It will still be in my unit folder (as orphan) but atleast it will be recoverable by me. Then the solutions you just gave are good but not reliable because on that ways users could not allow the login and program would not have access to the user files

Comment: Assuming you had create the shard folders on a service account it would own the folders and files and could share them with your employees.   Your employees would not / should probably not have access to delete a file owned by the service account.   Sharing the files with the employees would be done by the service account to there email address you wouldn't need access to there drive account.   Have you considered there may be an issue with how you have designed this application to work?

Comment: My answer is still correct by the way: "There is no way to automate the Oauth2 web browser popup window. That must be done manually at least once."

Comment: In my knowledge, even if someone created the shared folder, if I create a file in that folder and later delete it (writer permission can delete files) the file dissapear for the folder owner, so service account seems to be like nothing. And, as you anwered too, is there any other way to login without Oauth to do the multiple account login automatizhed?

Comment: First question: If I create a shared folder between the two of us.  And give you write access when you create the file you are owner, you can delete it.    I could create a script and have it running in the background to monitor this directory and update the permissions removing your owner access and giving it to the service account.  Or I could just have a service running to backup everything now and then.   Second question:  There are two types of Oauth2,  the kind that pops up the authentication window, and pre approved service accounts.   There is no multiple account login atomization.

Comment: Kinda sad for developers then since google have no way to administrate domain folders in drive and many other things where accesing to all users would be necesary...I still have the same problem but atleast you wasted your time answering me. Thanks :)

Comment: Not waiting my time any question that makes me think is fun its why I stalk stack.   Google for work and google domains I think have something that might help with this.   I don't have access it so haven't tried it but admin has writes to everyone else's account I think some how.

Comment: I kind of like your idea I may have to turn it into a tutorial or something.  Its a good use case for drive.

Comment: If you do it tell me! :D

Comment: its not true that there is no way to automate the logins. not so for google apps domains. look at drive api for user impersonation

Comment: Op didn't mention he had an apps domain account so I don't see the need to confuse the issue how ever I did mention it