Post a file to google drive using google/apiclient and laravel
I am trying post an a file to a google drive from a form in my laravel application, this is the code that should do that post,
Route::post('/file', [FileController::class, 'postForm'
private function postFile($filepath, $file) {
        try {
            $client = new GoogleClient();
            $client->setApplicationName(config('google.application_name'));
            $client->setAuthConfig(base_path('client_secret_574127095355-ns03k8as0g3hdqj0h2j6l32731jivg4r.apps.googleusercontent.com.json'));
            $client->setScopes(config('google.scopes'));

            $drive = new Drive($client);
            $fileMetaData = new DriveFile([
                'name' => $file->getClientOriginalName(),
            ]);

            $content = file_get_contents($file->getRealPath());

            $driveFile = $drive->files->create($fileMetaData, [
                'data' => $content,
                'mimeType' => $file->getMimeType(),
                'uploadType' => 'multipart',
                'fields' => 'id'
            ]);

            dd($driveFile);

        } catch(\Exception $e) {
           dd($e);
        }
    }

When firing this function I get the following error,

Code: 401. Message: Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.

Now I don't want to show a login pop for the user, I wanted to be authenticated as the server consuming the API, is this possible? I cannot find anything that explains how to get a token/refresh token and use them.
My assumption would be that I need to write a small piece of middleware to sit before my postFile method, that checks the authentication status and authenticates the server?

Based on the error you've got, your setup is using OAuth 2.0, which basically requires any user to log in with a Google account for authentication. In your use case, since you want to bypass login for authentication, your remaining option is to leverage the Service Account method. As per this official doc, "an application uses a service account when the application uses Google APIs to work with its own data rather than a user's data." For confirmation, are you indeed using the OAuth as your credential?

In your situation, this thread might be an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/q/36083274
